# Retrieving password for VPN in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, passwords, vpn

I'd like to retrieve a password I entered a while ago for a VPN in Max OS X Tiger (in the Internet Connect app) and have since forgotten.  It's probably stored with some simple obfuscation in some configuration file.  Anyone knows how to do retrieve it?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Look for the Keychain Access utility. It's in the Utilities folder, inside of the Applications folder.

Keychain Access allows you to look at all the passwords and keys stored (securely) in the system keychain.

With it, you should be able to find your VPN password.

Comment: Yep, that worked, thanks.  For further reference they are stored in the login keychain.

Comment: On Mavericks, it is in the system keychain, under the name of the VPN connection.